# Can't load bootstrap JS into an Electron app

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, electron

I'm making an Electron app. At the start of the index.htm file I have these lines:

```
   <script>require('./js/jquery.min.js');</script>
   <script>require('./js/popper.min.js');</script>
   <script>require('./js/bootstrap.min.js');</script>
```

With the corresponding files being in the stated locations. Loading the first two files happens OK, but when loading bootstrap, the following error happens:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'
Require stack:
- D:\E\electron-quick-start-master\js\bootstrap.min.js
- D:\E\electron-quick-start-master\index.html
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:627)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\common\reset-search-paths.js:41)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16)
    at D:\ElectronPlayground\electron-quick-start-master\js\bootstrap.min.js:6
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\E\electron-quick-start-master\js\bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\E\electron-quick-start-master\js\bootstrap.min.js:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:786)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798)
```

Following some of the older similar questions here, I tried this:

```
  <script>window.jQuery = window.$ = require('./js/jquery.min.js');</script>
  <script>require('./js/popper.min.js');</script>
  <script>require('./js/bootstrap.min.js');</script>
```

But it changes nothing. What's the problem?

Comment: Did my answer help you ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because jQuery isn't defined (globally in the window) because `module` is defined, therefore you can't access the jQuery variable as it doesn't exists really, this problem is caused by the following if statement in the library :

```
if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
  // set jQuery in `module`
} else {
  // set jQuery in `window`
}
```

You have two options to fix this issue, they are both simple and straightforward - as You need to simply declare the `jQuery` and `$` global variables with the value (the library itself) returned for the require method.:

**1. Fix with NPM**

Install jQuery into your project using the following command in the node command prompt :

`npm install jquery --save`

Now add the following code inside a script tag (or a js file):

`<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');</script>`

**2. Fix with jQuery library file**

If you don't install directly the jQuery library with NPM, that means you have simply the jQuery file somewhere in your project. To add the jQuery variable in the window, use require with the path to the jQuery library as first parameter:

```
<!-- If the require doesn't work, include first the jQuery file
<script src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>-->
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./jquery-3.0.0.min.js');</script>
```